# Snakemake rule not prducing output in slurm mode

Tags: python, snakemake

I only recently started using snakemake but so far it has been going really well and is taking alot of manual work off my shoulders. But now I ran into a problem which I just cannot figure out. I want to run a python program called spladder on a bunch of input files which were generated before. This works fine when I call snakemake directly `snakemake -c1`, but when I tell it to use slurm `snakemake -j1 --use-conda --slurm` there is no output from the script itself (including from `print()`). Only after the script finishes or fails for some reason I get the output from the script.
This is the rule which gives me headache:

```py
rule spladder:
    input:
        genomes = [f"../ressources/genomes/{genome}/genomic.gtf" for genome in accessions['genome_id'].unique()],
        bams = [f"data/alignments/{rsa}/{rsa}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam" for rsa in accessions.index]
    output:
        [f"data/spladder/{genome}/merge_graphs_mutex_exons_C3.pickle" for genome in accessions['genome_id'].unique()] 
    threads: 20
    resources:
        mem_mb=1024*20, 
        runtime=60*8 
    run:
        print("========RUNNING JOB SPLADDER=========")
        print("\n\n\n")
        print(input.genomes)
        for genome in input.genomes:
            genome_id = re.search(r'genomes/(.+?)/', genome).group(1)
            filtered_accessions = accessions[accessions['genome_id'] == genome_id]
            rsa_ids = filtered_accessions.index.values
            if len(rsa_ids) > 0:
                bam_files = [f"data/alignments/{rsa}/{rsa}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam" for rsa in rsa_ids]
                bam_files = ",".join(bam_files)
                print(f"running spladder for {genome} with {bam_files}")
                cmd = fr"""
                mkdir -p data/spladder/{genome_id}

                spladder build --set-mm-tag nM --bams {bam_files} --annotation {genome} \
                --outdir data/spladder/{genome_id} --parallel {threads}
                """
                shell(cmd)
```

When I call other (non-python) programs, such as STAR, the output is written into the slurm file in real time but I also noticed that the output of print() functions is only added once the program has finished.
How can I see the output of python code in my snakemake rules in real time?

Thanks in advance

Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flushing stdout can work, but also note that when executing through slurm, outputs are redirected to slurm output files instead of the console.

Here are some other issues you may want to look into:

- Your rule runs for all samples.  It's much better to generalize a rule to work for one sample and let snakemake deal with running samples separately.  When dealing with slurm you can run all genomes at once.
- Your rule may not produce all outputs.  If a genome doesn't have any rsa_ids, the output isn't produced.  This will cause all genome outputs to be deleted (see point above).
- Most of the python code in the run directive can be replaced with input functions and parameters to convert your command to a shell directive.
- You should use expand instead of list comprehensions, but once you convert your rule to a single genome you will eliminate most of these anyways.

Here's my refactor:

```py
rule all:
    '''
    Can replace with your consuming rule.  The important point is to
    perform the rsa_id filtering outside of the rule.  Otherwise snakemake
    will error when a requested genome doesn't have any values.
    Probably a cleaner way to do this, I copied what you had.  It seems
    impossible a genome could be in the accessions without having any rsa_ids?
    '''
    input: 
        expand(
            "data/spladder/{genome}/merge_graphs_mutex_exons_C3.pickle",
            genome = [genome_id 
                          for genome_id in accessions['genome_id'].unique() 
                          if len(accessions[accessions['genome_id'] == genome_id]) > 0,
                     ]
               )

def spladder_input(wildcards):
    '''This is needed to lookup rsa ids from genome.'''
    filtered_accessions = accessions[accessions['genome_id'] == wildcards.genome]
    rsa_ids = filtered_accessions.index.values
    return {
        'genome': "../ressources/genomes/{genome}/genomic.gtf",
        'bams': expand("data/alignments/{rsa}/{rsa}_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam", rsa=rsa_ids),
            }
rule spladder:
    input: unpack(spladder_input)
    output:
        "data/spladder/{genome}/merge_graphs_mutex_exons_C3.pickle"
    threads: 20  # sometimes it's better to use fewer threads and more jobs, consider decreasing
    resources:
        mem_mb=1024*20, 
        runtime=60*8 
    params:
        bams=labmda wildcards, input: ','.join(input.bams),
        outdir=lambda wildcards, output: Path(output).parent
    shell:  # this is how I like my shells formatted
        'spladder build '
            '--set-mm-tag nM '
            '--bams {params.bams} '
            '--annotation {input.genome} '
            '--outdir {params.outdir} '
            '--parallel {threads}'
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the effort of rewriting the code and giving advice on many potential issues :)

Answer (score -1):

I promise you I googled extensively and also prompted chatGPT before but it didn't yield any results. But then I pasted my whole stackoverflow question and, i guess because there is more context than in my previous prompts I got, what seems to me, the correct answer. Please take it with a grain of salt and if anyone has a better solution I am still happy to hear it. But here is what the AI said:

> It seems like you are encountering a buffering issue with the standard
> output when running your Snakefile with Slurm. This behavior can be
> influenced by how Python buffers its output. In the case of Slurm, the
> standard output is typically buffered when writing to files, which can
> lead to delayed printing of messages.
>
> To address this issue, you can try the following approaches:
>
> Flush the Output Buffer:
> Add explicit calls to `sys.stdout.flush()` after your print statements to force the buffer to be flushed immediately. Modify your
> run section like this:
>
> ```py
>     print("========RUNNING JOB SPLADDER=========")
>     print("\n\n\n")
>     print(input.genomes)
>     for genome in input.genomes:
>         # ... your existing code ...
>         print(f"running spladder for {genome} with {bam_files}")
>         cmd = fr"""
>         mkdir -p data/spladder/{genome_id}
>
>         spladder build --set-mm-tag nM --bams {bam_files} --annotation {genome} \
>         --outdir data/spladder/{genome_id} --parallel {threads}
>         """
>         shell(cmd)
>         sys.stdout.flush()  # Add this line
> ```
>
> Unbuffered Mode: Another approach is to run Python in unbuffered mode
> by setting the environment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED to a non-empty
> string. You can add this to the beginning of your Snakefile:
>
> ```py
>     import os
>
>     os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
> ```
>
> This will disable Python's output buffering and might provide real-time output in the Slurm logs.
>
> Try these modifications and see if they resolve the issue with delayed
> output in your Slurm jobs. If the problem persists, you may need to
> explore Slurm-specific configurations or consult the Snakemake
> documentation for any Slurm-specific recommendations.